# what happens if I click "delete backup" will I still have all my messages?

Tags: ios, icloud, backup, iphone

I currently upgraded but it still shows my other iPhone on iCloud. I don't want to delete it and then my messages erase. I have certain messages I want to keep.

What will happen if I do delete it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You will delete that backup, which has messages on **that backup.** The messages currently on phone, not in backup will remain in there peaceful state.